# How to use pagination on scoped Class in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

I am creating an app that with a long list of wikis (they are like posts). I am using Pundit in the app. I found two gems for pagination, [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) and [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari).

This is what WikiController looks like:

```
class WikisController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if current_user == nil
      @wikis = Wiki.visible_to_all
    else
      @wikis = policy_scope(Wiki) #pundit
    end
```

`visible_to_all` is a homemade scope to display all non-private Wikis to non-admin users.

```
#on Wiki.rb (model)
scope :visible_to_all, -> {where(private: [false, nil])}
```

Anyway, right now I have a plethora of wikis and would like to paginate them. 
`will_paginate` says to do this on relevant controller:

```
 class UserController

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
  end
```

Kaminari says to do this on controller:

```
@users = User.order(:name).page params[:page]
```

In my case `@users` will be `@wikis` because I am scoping `Wikis`; but `@wikis` is already used for scoping. How can I maintain my scope and paginate my Wikis?

Edit: wiki_policy.rb:

```
 def resolve
     wikis = []
     if user.role == 'admin'
       wikis = scope.all # if the user is an admin, show them all the wikis
     elsif user.role == 'premium'
       all_wikis = scope.all
       all_wikis.each do |wiki|
         if wiki.private == false || wiki.private == nil || wiki.user == user || wiki.users.include?(user)
           wikis << wiki # if the user is premium, only show them public wikis, or that private wikis they created, or private wikis they are a collaborator on
         end
       end
     else # this is the lowly standard user
       all_wikis = scope.all
       wikis = []
       all_wikis.each do |wiki|
         if wiki.private == false || wiki.users.include?(user)
           wikis << wiki # only show standard users public wikis and private wikis they are a collaborator on
         end
       end
     end
     wikis # return the wikis array we've built up
   end
```

Comment: Sidenote: Couldn't you integrate the .visible_to_all scope into the Pundit scope? The same current_user is available in the scope (just named as user) in the Pundit scope as well.

Comment: I will look it up! This is one of the very first rails app I have ever made, so it was not the most efficient. But that's a good suggestion! I will go back and refactor it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Wiki.visible_to_all` and `policy_scope(Wiki)` both return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, which can be furher scoped by chaining other functions.

All you need to do to get a page from a certain scope (or Relation), is to append the `.paginate` to it, like this:

```
@wikis = policy_scope(Wiki).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

**EDIT:** As for integrating the `visible_to_all`-scope into the Pundit-scope, you could do something like this:

```
def resolve
  if user.present?
    # current_user is present, get the normal scope here
  else
    scope.where(private: [false, nil])
  end
end
```

Comment: It returns `undefined method `paginate for #<Array:0x00...` error. I made sure that `require 'will_paginate'` is on Wikis Controller (and applications_controller); I made sure I restarted server as well, but it still does not work. I tested it with `@wikis = WIki.paginate(:...)` and it worked. It does not work with `policy_scope(Wiki)`. Do you know why?

Comment: Interesting... The `policy_scope` is returning an array. How is the resolve-method (presumably in the file wiki_policy.rb) defined?

Comment: I edited my post to include the `wiki_policy.rb`'s resolve method. What type of file is it supposed to return (is it not supposed to return an array?)

Comment: It can return an array, nothing is really preventing you from doing that. But an array is fundamentally different from a relation, and functions such as the `.paginate` won't work with it. I'd recommend you to try to make the filtering of wikis with `.where`, and let the database handle the filtering. What database are you using and how is the wiki.users association formed?